Double Filtering by date?
I know this is a very popular problem, but here goes. So I have an array of records coming in and need to filter them. I am filtering them by date, and I need them to be <=7 and >=1 days from today()s date.
const Today = new Date();
    const thirtyday = Today - 30;
    const sevenday = Today - 7;
    const oneday = Today - 1;
    const machinerecords = this.state.tasksnfiltered;


const due = machinerecords.filter(
      (record) =>
        Date.parse(record.nextdue) <= sevenday &&
        Date.parse(record.nextdue) >= oneday
    );

    {
      this.setState({ due: [...due] });
    }

I have also tried
machinerecords
      .filter((record) => Date.parse(record.nextdue) <= thirtyday)
      .filter((record) => Date.parse(record.nextdue) >= sevenday);

The info is coming from a backend I built.
I can get the first filter to run alone accurately for any of the date filters. but cant combine them.

This world be a good opportunity to put in some logging statements or breakpoints and check your assumptions. That should always be the first step: comparing what’s actually happening to what we think should be happening.

Most of the filtering logic can exist outside of the component.
Below, I spawned a couple tasks with dates ranging from half a day to ten days.
Only the tasks with a due date within two and five days should be displayed. This can be achieved by comparing two date objects. I assume your nextdue date is serialized into a timestamp e.g. YYYY-MM-DD.
const filterTasks = (tasks, afterDate, beforeDate) =>
  tasks.filter((task) => {
    const dueDate = Date.parse(task.nextdue);
    return dueDate >= afterDate && dueDate <= beforeDate;
  });

Here is a working React (function component) snippet.


const { useEffect, useMemo, useState, StrictMode } = React;

const DAY_IN_MILLIS = 8.64e7;

const addMillis = (date, millis) => new Date(date.getTime() + millis)

// Sweedish dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD
const tsFrom = (date, millis) => addMillis(date, millis).toLocaleDateString('sv-SE');

const now      = new Date();
const halfDay  = tsFrom(now, Math.floor(DAY_IN_MILLIS / 2));
const twoDays  = tsFrom(now, DAY_IN_MILLIS * 2);
const fiveDays = tsFrom(now, DAY_IN_MILLIS * 5);
const tenDays  = tsFrom(now, DAY_IN_MILLIS * 10);

const fetchTasks = () => Promise.resolve([
  { id: 1, nextdue: halfDay,  label: 'Half Day'  },
  { id: 2, nextdue: twoDays,  label: 'Two Days'  },
  { id: 3, nextdue: fiveDays, label: 'Five Days' },
  { id: 4, nextdue: tenDays,  label: 'Ten Days'  }
]);

const filterTasks = (tasks, afterDate, beforeDate) =>
  tasks.filter((task) => {
    const dueDate = Date.parse(task.nextdue);
    return dueDate >= afterDate && dueDate <= beforeDate;
  });

const TaskApp = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTasks().then(setTasks);
  }, []);
  
  const filteredTasks = useMemo(() => {
    const now = new Date();
    const oneDay = addMillis(now, DAY_IN_MILLIS * 1);
    const oneWeek = addMillis(now, DAY_IN_MILLIS * 7);
    return filterTasks(tasks, oneDay, oneWeek);
  }, [tasks]);
  
  return (
    <ul>
      {filteredTasks.map((task) => (
        <li key={task.id}>{task.label}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <TaskApp />
  </StrictMode>
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




In JavaScript dates have a millisecond representation so your code above is testing for dates between 7 and 1 milliseconds from today so depending on how your reference dates are generated something like the following may work as long as the h/m/s part of your dates are ignorable.
const Today = new Date.now(); // timestamp in milliseconds
    const thirtyday = Today - 30 * 24 * 3600000;
    const sevenday = Today - 7 * 24 * 3600000;
    const oneday = Today - 1 * 24 * 3600000;
    const machinerecords = this.state.tasksnfiltered;


const due = machinerecords.filter(
      (record) =>
        Date.parse(record.nextdue.getTime()) <= sevenday &&
        Date.parse(record.nextdue.getTime()) >= oneday
    );

For react though I generally use the date-fns library https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started as its really lightweight compared to momentjs.
date-fns handles ignoring h/m/s issues as well as 'enough' timezone handling to be useful.

Moment has been EOL since 2020, and should not be used in new projects. It has been replaced with Luxon. Here are other date library alternatives.

Anyways, date-fns is a good suggestion.
